# How to get and change EF object set elements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have database first application in mvc3. There is Rating table, it has **ID** and **Value** property in integer type. Count is 5 always. I want enter new Value, set it to the last element of Ratings and every element's value pass to before element's vaule. Values are sliping from last to first.

```
public ActionResult UpdateRating( int newValue )
{

var rating0 = db.Ratings.ElementAt( 0 );
var rating1 = db.Ratings.ElementAt( 1 );
var rating2 = db.Ratings.ElementAt( 2 );
var rating3 = db.Ratings.ElementAt( 3 );
var rating4 = db.Ratings.ElementAt( 4 );

rating0.Value = rating1.Value;
rating1.Value = rating2.Value;
rating2.Value = rating3.Value;
rating3.Value = rating4.Value;
rating4.Value = newValue ;

db.Ratings.Attach( rating0 );
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState( rating0 , EntityState.Modified );
db.Ratings.Attach( rating1 );
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState( rating1 , EntityState.Modified );
db.Ratings.Attach( rating2 );
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState( rating2 , EntityState.Modified );
db.Ratings.Attach( rating3 );
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState( rating3 , EntityState.Modified );
db.Ratings.Attach( rating4 );
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState( rating4 , EntityState.Modified );
db.SaveChanges();
...
}
```

I got error db.Ratings.ElementAt(); line. How can i do this operation?

Comment: What db.Ratings returns?

Comment: Error is so: 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MyProject.Database.Ratings ElementAt[Ratings](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyProject.Database.Ratings], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: db.Ratings is Ratings entity collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace with

```
public ActionResult UpdateRating( int newValue )
{

List<Rating> ratings = db.Ratings.OrderBy(r => r.id)
                        .ToList();

ratings[0].Value = ratings[1].Value;
ratings[1].Value = ratings[2].Value;
ratings[2].Value = ratings[3].Value;
ratings[3].Value = ratings[4].Value;
ratings[4].Value = newValue;

db.SaveChanges();
}
```